# How to prevent holes in external perimeter

Tags: retraction, bambu, seam

This dinosaur was printed on a Bambu Lab X1 Carbon with AMS, with 3rd party filament. Sliced with "Generic PLA" profile in Bambu Studio.

[image]

I understand that the zits probably happen at layer change, or hops to another location on the same layer.

I first reproduced that on a Benchy, by setting seams to random:
[image]
I understand that Benchy is a model where you'd *not* place the seams at random, but I wanted to make the problem visible in order to reduce the issue rather than hide it.

Here are some quicker prints showing my attempts to fix that with retraction:
[image]
Left: default of 0.8 mm retraction. Middle: 0 mm retraction (more stringing inside the cylinder, but no noticeable difference on the outside). Right: no retraction on layer change.

All seem to show similar amounts of holes.

Note that the printer does a flow calibration by printing some kind of linear advance pattern and analyzing it with lidar.

What else should I try to tune to minimize these holes?